# Fixing Seaborn AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'points_to_pixels'

Tags: python, seaborn

While learning Seaborn, I tried to visualize the iris dataset using the 'pairplot'.

Following is the dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris

The code I ran was:

```
sns.pairplot(iris, hue='species', diag_kind='kde')
```

I get the following error instead of the pairplot:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'points_to_pixels'
```

Comment: In my testing this issue only appeared when using the macOS backend for matplotlib, and only happened on macOS versions below 10.15

Answer (score 0):

How did you load the iris dataset into Python? There most likely lies your problem. However, an easier way to plot this dataset would be to load it directly through seaborn with:

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
```

Putting this together with your plotting command:

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris, hue='species', diag_kind='kde')
```

Which gave me the following plot:
[image]